# Preparing a web site for international usage

Tags: python, django, internationalization, project-planning

I am preparing to develop a web application that will (hopefully) be used by an audience with many different native languages.

What should I do to prepare my software project to have the user interface be almost entirely internationalized?

Are there any software stacks that make this easier?

Comment: Two parts i18n (internationalization) and l10n (localization). The software stack will depend on the technology (language and framework) you're using.

Comment: I was considering Django/Python because I have used it for other projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some resources you might want to see:

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/
- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/internationalization/
- http://www.djangobook.com/en/1.0/chapter18/

Python's `gettext` and `locale` module might also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

One big change in your project: you need to build in time to localize your strings.  Depending on your schedules, you may have to rearrange work so that all the string-changing work is at the front so that you have time to get the translations done before launching.

Or, alternately, you have to build in a buffer at the end to account for it.